# exim source code explanation can not implement

Tags: linux, exim

In exim source code, there is this file which also explains that using addresses in the format of `:include:pathname` will lead to reading of addresses from a file, yet I couldn't execute this behaviour.

It can be seen in  [this github link from exim's official repo](https://github.com/Exim/exim/blob/master/src/src/parse.c#L1247) at line starting 1369 it explains about addresses starting with format `:include:` inside function named in `parse_forward_list()` which would allow to read address from a file.

yet if i try the address in a way such as,

```
VRFY :include:/usr/path
501 missing or malformed local part (expected word or "<")
VRFY <:include:/usr/path>
501 missing or malformed local part
```

I get the behaviour above, how can I use `:include:` format?

Answer (score 2):

I am almost positive that the "addresses starting with format :include:" behavior is referring to addresses provided in the config, not via an smtp exchange.  It would be a really, really bad idea to allow senders to reference arbitrary files.

In this specific case, the "missing or malformed local part" error is being triggered by the colons in your local part (see mac_iscntrl_or_special in [macros.h](https://github.com/Exim/exim/blob/master/src/src/macros.h#L72)